# Need assistance regarding sorting in fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

My table is populating using `fetchedResultsController`. I want to sort the data but conditionally on two things:

1. Name of users.
2. Scores.

a. If there is no score the table must to sorted with users name alphabetically.

b. If any user has score that must go on top.

I tried this

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"userScore" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

It works fine but after app restart table is sorted only by user name.

Comment: Please explain: 'after app restart all settings are out'

Comment: @Wain I updated the post. Please view.